# Log with % resources used on python script

Tags: python, ubuntu

What is it the best way to create a log that resume the percentage of resources (ram, cpu ...) used in each execution of python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) library and the `getrusage` function is the solution you're looking for, but it will only inform you of the memory used, not the cpu.

Other option is execute a unix command like [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) through a bash script and save the results.